# Calibri font for a particular set of line in Rmarkdown

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, knitr, kable

Here's a reproducible example of PDF Rmarkdown:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

```{r cars}
summary(cars)
```
````

I need ***"This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com."***

to be in Calibri font than the default one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are okay with setting the latex engine to xelatex, you can use `\fontspec{Calibri}` to set the font to Calibri and then `\normalfont` to return to the default font.

```r
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  pdf_document: 
    latex_engine: xelatex
---

## R Markdown

\fontspec{Calibri} 

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

\normalfont

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:
```

[image: knitted pdf]